# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while initializing 2D array entries to 0

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, 2d

I need to create a dynamic 2D array which the user can edit. I've tried many different ways and even tried to do it separately to easier diagnose, but always get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Below is some code (not from my project) that shows the problem. I get the error when I try to fill the board with `0`.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int rows = 0;
        int cols = 0;
        int[][] board = new int[rows][cols];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter in a row  :");
        rows = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter in a col :");
        cols =scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)  {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)  {
            board[i][j] = 0;
                    System.out.print ("\t" + board[i][j]);                       
                } 
            System.out.print ("\n"); 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you instantiate the `board` array? can you post that code?

Comment: what error do you get? Can you post the text?

Comment: Seems that you are missing the new board[rows][cols] right after the rows cols being set

Comment: Is an array the only approach you have tried?  If you need the user to change the array dynamically, wouldn't a `List<>` or `ArrayList<>` be better options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're initializing the array with 0 rows and 0 columns. That's having place for nothing. If a user inputs 1 and 1 for rows and columns, you try to access the first row. But there is no row.

You should initialize your board after getting the amount of rows and columns from the user.

```
int rows = 0; // the Java default value for integers is 0. Equivalent: int rows;
int cols = 0; // equivalent: int cols;

Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

System.out.print("Enter in a row  :");
rows = scan.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter in a col :");
cols =scan.nextInt();

int[][] board = new int[rows][cols]; // now has values other than 0

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
   {
      board[i][j] = 0;
      System.out.print ("\t" + board[i][j]);                         
   } 
   System.out.print ("\n"); 
}
```

Ideally, you would want to verify user input to see that they give dimensions that make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. You are initializing your array with `[0][0]` dimensions. Take a closer look at what values `rows` and `cols` have.

**Fix:**

Allow a maximum of `n` rows and `m` cols. 
e.g. `int rows = 5, cols = 6`

or just move your array initalization after you've read `rows` and `cols` from the `Scanner`.

**Go nuts:**

```
int rows = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int cols = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
```

Comment: "Go nuts: [...]" That's a total waste of space. While I see the humour in the statement, this is not something I would recommend to someone who's only just learning Java.

Answer (score 1):

If think, it should be something like this:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main (String args[]) { 
        int rows = 0; 
        int cols = 0; 
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

       System.out.print("Enter in a row  :");
       rows = scan.nextInt();
       System.out.print("Enter in a col :");
       cols = scan.nextInt();

       int[][] board = new int[rows][cols]; 

       for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
           {
               board[i][j] = 0;
               System.out.print ("\t" + board[i][j]);                         
           } 
           System.out.print ("\n"); 
       }
    } 
}
```